# программно нажать и отпустить кнопку мыши

Tags: java, мышь

Существует ли возможность с помощью java программно вызывать нажатие кнопок мыши, а не отлавливать событие...

А вообще, интересует небольшой скрипт, который бы при нажатии левой клавиши мыши(`mouse_down`) сразу бы отпускал(`mouse_up`). Т.е. что-бы нельзя было зажать клавишу, только одиночные клики. Не в отдельной программе, а везде. В java ничего такого не видел...)

Comment: джава работает внутри виртуальной машины. внутри джава программы имитировать нажатие кнопки мыши возможно.

Comment: про эмуляцию мышки вот http://javist.ru/imitacii-myshi-i-nazhatiya-klavish/ , а что вы понимаете под скриптом? на каком языке??

Comment: Да неважно на каком языке, лишь бы можно было пользоваться сразу) Сейчас попробую с роботом, но меня терзают смутные сомнения))

Comment: Все же можно с помощью робота решить проблему. Не идеально, т.к. нет слушателя, что-бы можно было реагировать на нажатие клавиши. Но можно просто вызывать  robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); каждые 50 мс... оптимизация так себе, но работает. Вынесите свой коммент как вопрос, отмечу...

Хотя, где-то видел что есть глобальный слушатель мыши, тогда можно нормально сделать.

Comment: Ага, слушатель сделал с помощью JNativeHook. Всем спасибо.